# Will an object be GC'ed if I save a reference to it in its finalize method?

Tags: java, android, memory, garbage-collection, finalizer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reference to object during finalize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002567/reference-to-object-during-finalize)

I have an Object which is eligible for garbage collection, but within its `finalize` method, I save a reference to that Object, say by calling `arrayList.add(this)`.

Will the object still get garbage collected?

Comment: Bottom line: don't use `finalize`.  Please.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: No. The long answer is: Yes. The first time the finalize method is called  it will "resurrect", however, when the variable becomes eligible for GC again, the finalize method will not be called and it will be GC'ed.

Comment: can you elaborate please i couldn't understand this

Comment: @JaiPandit What part of it don't you understand? It seems perfectly clear to me.

Comment: Finalize only gets called once.